# Using a const void* with string

Tags: c++, pointers

In c++11, I have a function that takes a const void* data and a size_t dataSize, so I have to pass to the function the pointer to a string.

```
function_test( const void* Data, size_t DataSize)
{
   std::string received_data((const char*)Data, DataSize);
   if (received_data=="1")
   {
      //do stuff... I need enter here
   }
}
```

I use:

```
    std::string test1 = "1";
    function_test(&test1, sizeof(test1));
```

I expect that received_data is equal to "1" but it's not, why? How can I fix this?

Comment: "I need to have the const void* of it" why? It seems you are confusing the pointer to the `std::string` and the pointer to the character array stored by that string.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? If you need to copy the string you can do `std::string test3 = test1;`

Comment: `std::string test3((const char*)test2, sizeof(test1));` this doesn't do what you need. What is wrong with simple assignment `std::string test3 = test1;`?

Comment: If you want a pointer to first character of the underlying array of `test1`, that's spelled `test1.c_str()`. Also, `sizeof` does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: You cast it *from* the type `std::string*` to a type `const void*`, and then cast it back to the type `const char*` which is a completely different type. Maybe cast it back to a `std::string*`?

Answer (score 2):

> Why test3 is not "1"?

Because `std::string` is not an array of char. A pointer to `std::string` is not a pointer to the buffer that `std::string` class manages where the content of the string is stored. When you reinterpret a pointer to a `std::string` object as a pointer to char, you get a meaningless representation of the internals of the `std::string` object.

---

> I need that test3 is equal to "1"

Then use the copy constructor:

```
std::string test3(test1);
```

---

P.S. Don't use C-style casts. Use C++ style `static_cast` etc. This will make it easier to understand the program that you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to pass a `const void*` to a legacy C-style API, you need to use:

```
 std::string test;
 reinterpret_cast<const void*>(test.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not C.

What you show is close to the following C snippet:

```
char test1[] = "1";
const void* test2 = test1;  // test1 decays to a pointer

char test3[sizeof(test1)];
strcpy(test3, test2);
```

But a C++ `std::string` is a complex container with internal data for housekeeping *and* an array of characters accessible through the `data` or `c_str` method:

```
std::string test1 = "1";
const void* test2 = test1.c_str();

std::string test3(static_cast<const char*>(test2), sizeof(test1));
```

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number • sorry for the ambiguity, I was referring to the latter use of `sizeof(test1)` in the second code snippet.

Comment: @Eljay indeed, thats wrong